# How to use Backbone.EventBinder with views

Tags: events, backbone.js, marionette, backbone.eventbinder

Referring to [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/10/01/backbone-eventbinder-better-event-management-for-your-backbone-apps/) post on Backbone.EventBinder, I am lost on how to use EventBinder with Backbone views (which is the most popular use case). Is it still recommend to add a close() method to the Backbone.View prototype and a onClose() method to the view as suggested in [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) post? Also where does one store the binder object, so that binder.unbindAll() can be called on close? What is the recommended way to close child views (e.g. a parent view on a collection which has child views on the associated models). A working example would be a great addition to the Backbone.EventBinder project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should still add a `close` method to your views. The EventBinder does not negate any of what that Zombies post says. Rather, it helps to automate a lot of the process by making it easier to unbind all of your events within the view.

Take a look at the Marionette.View source code for an example of how it's used:

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.view.js#L9
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.view.js#L16
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.view.js#L97

If you're using Marionette, you don't need to add the `close` method yourself, or add the event binder yourself. That's handled for you.

If you want to add this to your own views, it's easy:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){

    // add the event binder
    this.eventBinder = new Backbone.EventBinder();

    // bind some stuff
    this.eventBinder.bindTo(this.model, "change:foo", this.doStuff, this);
  },

  close: function(){
    // ... other stuff

    this.eventBinder.unbindAll();
  }
});
```